# Minimum of Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, poisson-distribution

I'm not entirely sure how to go about solving this problem.

[image]

At first glance I thought W was obviously the minimum, as the mean is 1. However, $Pr(W < 2 ) e^{-1}*(1 +1) = .7357$, which is not one of the available options.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $W, X, Y$ are independent so that
\begin{align}
& P[\min(W, X, Y) \leq 2] = 1 - P[\min(W, X, Y) > 2] \\
= & 1 - P[W > 2, X > 2, Y > 2] \\
= & 1 - P[W > 2]P[X > 2]P[Y > 2].
\end{align}
Now apply the Poisson distribution law for each probability, can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes absolutely.